# Undefined method error on class attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I'm new to Ruby on Rails so please forgive me if the question is somehow stupid.

I'm currently following the guide [here](https://ihower.tw/rails4/restful-practices.html).(It's written in Traditional Chinese).

And in that chapter, the author is talking about setting the status of a resource.

First, it edited the app/model/event.rb file

```
def closed?
  self.status == "CLOSED"
end

def open?
  !self.closed?
end

def open!
  self.status = "OPEN"
  self.save!
end

def close!
  self.status = "CLOSED"
  self.save!
end
```

Then the config/routes.rb file.

```
resources :events do
    resource :state, :controller => 'event_states'
    # ...
end
```

Then the app/view/events/show.html.erb file and insert the following code.

```
<p>Status: <%= @event.status %></p>

<p>
<% if @event.closed? %>
    <%= link_to '[Open]', event_state_path(@event ), :method => :post %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to '[Close]', event_state_path(@event), :method => :delete %>
 <% end %>
</p>
```

I understand that it's trying to toggle the status of an event through the POST and DELETE http request, but I get the "NoMethod" error on the show page. Which is understandable(?) cause there's no such variable in the class "event".

```
undefined method `status' for #<Event:0x007f5e59b3b988>

  <% end %>
</p>
<p>Status : <%= @event.status %></p>

<p>
<% if @event.closed? %>
```

Any thoughts on this problem?
(Please tell me if you need other information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you probably miss the previous chapter https://ihower.tw/rails4/basic.html

Somewhere a quarter into the page, it added a migration to add the `status` attribute to the `event` model. via

```
rails g migration add_status_to_events
```

And carried out some migrations.

In case you are not familiar with migration, I'd strongly suggest you to check out migrations on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html